# "wmi driver extensions" "windows server 2008" how to install

Tags: windows-server-2008, wmi

I'm trying to setup a Services on a Win2008 64 bit server. This services depends on the WMI Driver Extensions, but I can't find where to install it from or download it to install.

Does anyone have any ideas where I could find the resources to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they exist on server 2008 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation#WMI_driver_extensions Virtual machine time, maybe?

Comment: Thanks yasth, you are correct. FOr some reason they were installed on a 32bit 2008 server but could not get them on a 64bit server. It turns out the issue the services would not start was because the C++ runtime was not available, not because of the WMI driver dependency.